# Including a date filter into a matrix formula

Tags: excel

I have the following table in which I want go get a Top5 in cells E2:E6 based on the values in column C.

```
           A             B         C        D        E        F        G 
    1                                     From    01.02.015   to   28.02.2015
    2    David      01.01.2015     5 €              *
    3    Mark       01.02.2015     10 €             *
    4    Peter      15.03.2015     7 €              *
    5    Carolin    19.02.2015     8 €              *
    6    Andrea     20.08.2015     3 €              *
    7    Markus     17.05.2015     15 €
    8    Sven       06.03.2015     5 €
    9    Konrad     08.02.2015     12 €
    :
    :
```

To get the Top5 I am using so far the following matrix formula in cells E2:E6:

```
={INDEX($A$2:$A$1000000;MATCH(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$1000000);$C$2:$C$1000000-ROWS($A$2:$A$1000000)/9^9);ROWS(A1));$C$2:$C$1000000-ROWS($C$2:$C$1000000)/9^9;0))}
```

This formula works perfectly. Now I want to add a filter *(as you can see in Cell E1 and Cell G1)* to select the Top5 by the dates in column B. In this case only the persons who have a value between 01.02.2015 and 28.02.2015 should be included into the Top5 in cell E2:E6 *(Mark, Carolin, Konrad)*.

So far I have tried the following matrix formula for this:

```
  ={INDEX(IF(AND($B$2:$B$100000>=$E$1;$B$2:$B$100000<=$G$1);$A$2:$A$1000000;"");MATCH(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(IF(AND($B$2:$B$100000>=$E$1;$B$2:$B$100000<=$G$1);$C$2:$C$1000000;""));$C$2:$C$1000000-ROWS($A$2:$A$1000000)/9^9);ROWS(A1));$C$2:$C$1000000-ROWS($C$2:$C$1000000)/9^9;0))}
```

However, I get a #VALUE! error from it.

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue and include the date filters into the matrix formula?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: I think you must have translated your formula incorrectly. I presume those cases of ROWS should actually be ROW; otherwise your formula will not work at all. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It is "ROW" instead of "ROWS" so the formula would be: ={INDEX(IF(AND($B$2:$B$100000>=$E$1;$B$2:$B$100000<=$G$1);$A$2:$A$1000000;"");MATCH(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(IF(AND($B$2:$B$100000>=$E$1;$B$2:$B$100000<=$G$1);$C$2:$C$1000000;""));$C$2:$C$1000000-ROW($A$2:$A$1000000)/9^9);ROW(A1));$C$2:$C$1000000-ROW($C$2:$C$1000000)/9^9;0))}

Comment: Thanks. Do you really have data extending all the way to row 1 million?? Any array formula set-up will practically crash your system with that amount of data to process.

Comment: No, the 1.000.000 is just in the formula so I can add data to the table and not have to worry about if the formula considers it. So far the datas only go to row 10 in my original sheet.

Comment: But you cannot arbitrarily reference a large row number with no detriment to performance. Using 1,000,000 means that, if you only actually have data to row 10, you are forcing Excel to perform 999,990 calculations more than necessary. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), array formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

Comment: O.K. then I will shorten those formulas to a lower number. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$20>=$E$1,IF($B$2:$B$20<=$G$1,IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$20),$C$2:$C$20-ROW($A$2:$A$20)/9^9))),ROWS(A$1:A1)),$C$2:$C$20-ROW($C$2:$C$20)/9^9,0))`

Amend the 20 to a suitable upper bound.

Regards

Comment: Pretty creative with the row(range) /9^9. I'm going to have to steal that one and add it to my collection. ;) Is using 9^9 a standard or just a personal preference?

Comment: That was the OP's choice, so I just copied it! Though I also tend to use that value for some reason. Perhaps the appeal of the number 9 at some subconscious level!

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your great answer and your help. It works perfectly :-) I just had to modify the "ROWS($A$1:A1)" part in your formula. =INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$20>=$E$1,IF($B$2:$B$20<=$G$1,IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$20),$C$2:$C$20-ROW($A$2:$A$20)/9^9))));ROW(A1)),$C$2:$C$20-ROW($C$2:$C$20)/9^9,0))

Comment: You're welcome, but actually that was a deliberate change: ROWS is a much more rigorous choice than ROW for LARGE's (or SMALL's) k parameter: http://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/